# Save facebook profile picture in model using python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth

How to store the get Facebook profile picture of a user while logging in through Facebook and saving it in my userprofile model.

I found this link which says how to do so using django-social-auth, https://gist.github.com/kalamhavij/1662930. but signals is now deprecated and I have to use pipeline.

Any idea how can I do the same using python-social-auth and pipeline?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how it worked with me. (from https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/80)

Add the following code to pipeline.py:

```
from requests import request, HTTPError

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile


def save_profile_picture(strategy, user, response, details,
                         is_new=False,*args,**kwargs):

    if is_new and strategy.backend.name == 'facebook':
        url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture'.format(response['id'])

        try:
            response = request('GET', url, params={'type': 'large'})
            response.raise_for_status()
        except HTTPError:
            pass
        else:
            profile = user.get_profile()
            profile.profile_photo.save('{0}_social.jpg'.format(user.username),
                                   ContentFile(response.content))
            profile.save()
```

and add to pipelines in settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE += (
'<application>.pipelines.save_profile_picture',
)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. the user parameter is None. Any ideas?

Comment: One thing nobody mentions is you need to have the default pipeline variable setup properly in SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE. Using += doesn't work, and simply setting the pipeline to save_profile_picture doesn't work. Make sure you set default pipeline variables here http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/pipeline.html

Comment: for those who want a bigger version of the image, do : `url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type=large'.format(response['id'])`

Comment: where is the image stored?

Comment: Another way to get image url is `response["picture"]["data"]["url"]`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you already configured `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE`, there aren't many differences with signals approach.

Just create needed pipeline (skipping all imports, they're obvious)

```
def update_avatar(backend, details, response, social_user, uid,\
                  user, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.__class__ == FacebookBackend:
        url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large" % response['id']
        avatar = urlopen(url)
        profile = user.get_profile()
        profile.profile_photo.save(slugify(user.username + " social") + '.jpg', 
                            ContentFile(avatar.read()))              
        profile.save()
```

and add to pipelines:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE += (
    '<application>.pipelines.update_avatar',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers may not work (it did not work for me) as the facebook profile URL does not work anymore without accesstoken. The following answer worked for me.

```
def save_profile(backend, user, response, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    if is_new and backend.name == "facebook":
    #The main part is how to get the profile picture URL and then do what you need to do
        Profile.objects.filter(owner=user).update(
            imageUrl='https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture/?type=large&access_token={1}'.format(response['id'],
                                                                                                  response[
                                                                                                      'access_token']))
```

add to the pipeline in setting.py,

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE+ = ('<full_path>.save_profile')
```